# How to use the LazyConstraintCallback in the CPLEX Python API to solve a MILP problem through Benders' decomposition

Tags: python, cplex

I have a MILP problem with binary and continuous variables. I want to use the Benders' decomposition algorithm to solve it. I am following this presentation: http://www.iems.ucf.edu/qzheng/grpmbr/seminar/Yuping_Intro_to_BendersDecomp.pdf

I separate my problem into a master problem composed of the discrete variables and a slave problem that has the continuous variables.

I am using the CPLEX Python API to solve it, based on the ATSP example: https://github.com/cswaroop/cplex-samples/blob/master/bendersatsp.py

I create the master problem and the dual of the slave as in this example.

I use the `BendersLazyConsCallback`, but I am not sure I understand it entirely. Please help me through.

The function `separate` is called when the current master solution is obtained, then the dual objective function is updated, and the dual problem is re-solved.

If the dual is unbounded then it adds the ray to the master problem constraints, e.g., `self.add(constraint = workerLP.cutLhs, sense = "L", rhs = workerLP.cutRhs)`, which happens in the `BendersLazyConsCallback` class.

But the example does not include the code when the dual is optimal.
So, when the dual is optimal, I add a similar call and add the constraint to the master problem based on the dual solution.

However, if I try to print the master problem constraints, e.g., `problem.linear_constraints.get_rows()`, I do not see the newly included constraints. It seems that the `self.add(constraint = workerLP.cutLhs, sense = "L", rhs = workerLP.cutRhs)` command does not push this to the master constraints but keeps it as a member of the `LazyConstraintCallback` class. Is this correct? How can I see that these new constraints are actually added?

Also, how does the algorithm stop? In the traditional Benders' algorithm the lower and upper bounds of the problem are updated based the the dual and master solution and when they are equal we have convergence. 
In the ATSP example, I don't see where this is happening. When exactly is the `BendersLazyConsCallback` triggered and how does it know when to stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example that you linked to above is from CPLEX 12.6. This is quite old, by now (currently, the latest version is [12.9](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/Optimization_Studio/topics/COS_home.html)). If you haven't updated to a more recent version yet, it would probably be a good idea to do so. One reason to update is that with CPLEX 12.7, there is support for [automatic Benders' decomposition](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/CPLEX/ReleaseNotes/topics/releasenotes127/newBenders.html). With CPLEX 12.8, there is a new [generic callback](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/CPLEX/ReleaseNotes/topics/releasenotes128/newCallbacks.html) (and a new `bendersatsp2.py` example to demonstrate it).

With that said, I'll try to answer some of your other questions.

First, as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=fc41b7a7-5c14-4b25-96a1-016e6cc17339), if you write out the model, it will not include the lazy constraints that you have added dynamically in the callback. You can print them out in the callback yourself easily enough (e.g., `print("LC:", workerLP.cutLhs, "G", workerLP.cutRhs)`. You can determine if your constraints have been applied, by the presence of a message at the end of the engine log, like:

> User cuts applied:  3

As to your final questions about how lazy constraints work, please see the section on [legacy callbacks](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/progr_adv/callbacks_basic/01_cb_title_synopsis.html) in the CPLEX User's Manual. Also, there is the section on [termination conditions of the MIP optimizer](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/mip/usage/11_terminate.html). The lazy constraint callback is invoked whenever CPLEX finds an integer feasible solution (see [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014791810) thread on the IBM developerWorks forum for more on that).

Comment: Hello,

thank you very much for your prompt reply.

The links you provide are very helpful.

Comment: Hello, I am using the latest CPLEX version, and updated my code to match the one at the bendersatsp2.py example. The problems that i encounter are the following.

1) the worker that solves the linear problem in some cases gives a solution status: optimal_infeasible. I don't really understand this solution. What does this mean exactly. 

2) One thing that i am doing differently from the example bendersasp2.py is that when i get the ray, i push the new cut (self.cutLhs) based on the names of the variables rather than the position. I don't think this is a problem, right?

Comment: Also, i assume that for example the value at ray[0] corresponds to the 1st variable of the objective function right?

Comment: 1) The solution status optimal_infeasible corresponds to [CPX_STAT_OPTIMAL_INFEAS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/macros/CPX_STAT_OPTIMAL_INFEAS.html) in the C API.

Comment: 2) Using names instead of indices should be fine. It is, however, not very efficient. If possible, it's better to maintain a names-to-index dictionary yourself and convert to indices before passing into CPLEX. Yes, `ray[0]` corresponds to the first variable added to the model which is the same as the first variable in the objective function. See also [CPXgetray](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/cpxapi/getray.html).